# Validation of Class Diagram: Is the Proposed Model Accurate?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am not sure if i made this correctly, the meldingen is part of dossier. But there is a tool thats will make controles to check if the status of the tool is true, if this is correct than it wil make a check if the dossier_id can be find inside the data. If this is also true it should made a message that wil be shown inside the dossier.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/602rq.png)

Please help advice

I tried to make the classes and controlles classes and melding is part of dossier, so i made a line from melding to dossier with generalization. But i am not sure that this is correct.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your question. Unfortunately, reviewing a full diagram is out if scope of the website. This is way to broad and is rarely useful to other people that the requester. Could you narrow down your question on one specific point where you have a doubt and explain why you are unsure ?